Updated React Native App to target SDK 34 and registered receiver also in MainApplication.java but still getting crash
Updated my react native app target sdk version to 34 but got error One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED so added this code in MainApplication class
registered receiver in mainapplication.java class
@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 34) {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}

but still getting error Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false when triggered from Activity.onStop please help.

This question is similar to: What is the proper way to use registerReceiver in Android 14/SDK 34?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I encountered the same issue, but this solution worked for me.
Open MainApplication.java file and add this code
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Build;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

@Override
public Intent registerReceiver(@Nullable BroadcastReceiver receiver, 
IntentFilter filter) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34 && getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion >= 
34) {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter, 
Context.RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
    } else {
        return super.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }
}

make sure to add this code above the oncreate() method.
add this line inside android/app/build.gradle dependencies.
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'

